# '$' char in method parameter is for any purpose?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

is there any good reason to add the char '**$**' to parameter name of a method ?
is different `<childComponent @updateMissionPriority="updateMissionPriority($event)" />` compared to `<childComponent @updateMissionPriority="updateMissionPriority(param)" />` ?

Comment: There's nothing special about `$` in variable names. However, `$event` is a built-in variable in Vue.js, `param` isn't.

Comment: There is no reason at all to prefix a method param name with `$`. But there is a [very good reason](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#accessing-event-argument-in-inline-handlers) to pass `$event` to a native handler.

Comment: @Barmar when should use that built-in variable over other variables ? which cases ?

Comment: @tao but in the given example **updateMissionPriority** is not a native handler

Comment: Read the documentation to learn what `$event` is used for.

Comment: I never said it was. The first part of my previous comment answers your question. The second part is only added for completeness. In your second `<childComponent />` example `param` is `undefined`.

Comment: well I don't understand what is meant by "**need to access the original DOM event**"